# Puppet module level hiera for setting dependency values

Tags: module, overriding, puppet, hiera

I have created a puppet module and wish to use (hiera 5) module-level hiera to set values for dependencies.  I have created a hiera.yaml, data dir and common.yaml.  However, module hiera values do not appear to be passed to the dependencies, and I have to set the hiera at the environment level instead (which is then not self contained within the module).

It appears that hiera keys only resolve with the local module prefix.

The dependency I am targeting is fervid/secure_linux_cis and I need to set some hiera for it's classes with 'enforced => false'.  Doing this in a manifest isn't 100% effective as a few classes present as duplicate resources.

Essentially, what I want to be able to do in my module's common.yaml is:

```
---
my::module::key1:  'value'
secure_linux_cis::redhat7::cis_1_1_2:enforced: false
```

Using the above example, I can resolve the my::module value but the dependency secure_linux_cis value is ignored.

Is there a way to get module level hiera to pass values to a dependency?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get module level hiera to pass values to a dependency?

Not directly, no.  Automatic data binding performs Hiera lookups in the context of the class whose parameters are being looked up, not that of the one declaring it.  In your case, then, it is the hiera data of module `secure_linux_cis` that will be consulted for default values for the parameters of class `secure_linux_cis::redhat7::cis_1_1_2`.

If you are willing to risk using a resource-like declaration of that class, then you should be able to do something along these lines:

```
class my::module(
    String $key1
) {
    $cis112_enforced = lookup('secure_linux_cis::redhat7::cis_1_1_2:enforced', Boolean, undef, false)
    class { 'secure_linux_cis::redhat7::cis_1_1_2': enforced => $cis112_enforced }
}
```

Of course, that carries all the risks attending resource-like class declarations.  I don't actually recommend it.  You could consider instead setting the parameter in a per-node level of the environment-level data.  You might also consider looking at the Roles & Profiles pattern, for resource-like class declarations make a little bit more sense in a profile class.

Comment: I have used resource class declarations for some of the subclasses, however it gets duplicate resources for a few as the module author has also, eg he has used:

    class { '::secure_linux_cis::redhat7::cis_4_2_1_1':
      logging => $logging,
    }

This prevents me doing the same in my wrapping class.  I have tried using a collector, however it fails to compile as 'classes cannot be collected'.  I have had to fall back to using hiera at the environment level, but would still like to set all 'enforced => false' parameters at the module that I have written to wrap the dependency.

Comment: Then you seem to be in a bit of a bind, @xit.  As I already wrote, a class reads module-level data only from its own module.  Class parameters take their values from (1) a resource-like declaration, or (2) environment-level data, or (3) module-level data for their module, or (4) global data, or (5) built-in defaults, in that order.  There can be at most one resource-like declaration of any given class.  If you can't do (1) and can't or won't do (2) or (4), then I don't see how you'll achieve the behavior you want without modifying the `secure_linux_cis` module.

Comment: Thanks John, I thought this may be the case but hoped there was a way around it.  Resource collectors seemed hopeful but don't work for classes.  Your input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`secure_linux_cis::redhat7::cis_1_1_2::enforced`

This should work. You missed one `:` in your example.